# Display active language flag with Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, translation

Here is [my website](http://www.johanndacosta.fr/).

As you can see on the top-right, I managed to display a dropdown menu with language selector inside. Now I want to display the active flag in the navbar.

Any idea?

Comment: Active language flag is showing correctly on the navbar. Do you want to mark active flag in dropdown too?

Comment: Thanks @Dmonix, I got what I needed now.